# Quotient of $\text{Proj}(A)$ by the action of a finite group

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, schemes, graded-rings-modules

Let $X$ be $ \operatorname{Proj}(A)$ for some graded ring A, and let $G$ be a finite group acting on $A$ with morphisms of graded rings; consequently $G$ acts on $X$.

I know I can write $X = \bigcup_{f\in A^+}X_f$ where $X_f=\{p \in X \mid f \notin p\}$.

Is it true that the quotient $X/G$, as a topological space, can be written as $X/G = \bigcup_{f\in A^G}p(X_f)$ ?
With $p:X \to X/G$ I intend the projection, while $A^G $ is the subring of $G$ invariants element of $A$.

I tried to prove it, but no idea on how to proceed. Any help/hint would be appreciated!

Comment: Answered at [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4023567/quotient-of-operatornameproj-a-by-the-action-of-a-finite-group).

Comment: Yes, here is the link: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4023567/quotient-of-operatornameproj-a-by-the-action-of-a-finite-group